# Can apps created using Quickly for Ubuntu be used in other linux distros?

Tags: application-development, python, quickly

I need to write a small program to update my mongodb. I'm currently on ubuntu but I need to use it on other linux distributions. I would just like to make sure that applications using this method:

http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/

Can be run on other distros?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes, you can

By default quickly uses pyGOBJECT for creating applications, It is a cross platform so you can use these apps in other linux distros. But you may need to make tiny changes in the code because there are some ubuntu specifc features like application indicator which is not available in other distros.

Comment: Can you show me (e.g. a link for tutorial) how to adapt app indicator in other distro?